# c# allowing slashes (and other similar characters) in regular expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I am trying to validate a string based on the inputed characters. I want to be able to set which characters are allowed besides characters and numbers. Below is my extension method:

```
public static bool isAlphaNumeric(this string inputString, string allowedChars)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(allowedChars);
    str.Replace(" ", "\\s");
    str.Replace("\n","\\\\");
    str.Replace("/n", "////");
    allowedChars = str.ToString();

    Regex rg = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9" + allowedChars + "]*$");
    return rg.IsMatch(inputString);
}
```

The way I use this is:

```
s string = " te\m@as 1963' yili.ışçöÖÇÜ/nda olbnrdu" // just a test string with no meaning
if (s.isAlphaNumeric("ışŞö\Ö@üÜçÇ ğ'Ğ/.")) {...}
```

Of course it gives an error:

```
parsing "^[a-zA-Z0-9ışŞö\Ö@üÜçÇ\sğ'Ğ/.]*$" - Unrecognized escape sequence
```

the stringbuilder replace function is wrong which I am aware of. I want to be able to accept all characters given in the allowedChars parameter. This can also include slashes (any other characters similar to slashes I am not aware of?) Given this, how can I get my replace function work? and also is the way I am doing is correct? I am very very new to regular expressions and have no clue on how to work with them...

Comment: The code you've given won't even compile. It's not going to get as far as putting `^[`a-zA-Z0-9` on the front. Could you post your *actual* test code?

Comment: Jon, I don't understand why it doesn't compile. It works ok here.. Thank you for trying to help though..

Comment: The exact code you've given (underneat the "The way I use this is")? I really don't think so. On the first line: the variable name and type are the wrong way round, there's a `\m` in the string literal, and you've got no semi-colon. There's *no way* that's your real code.

Comment: By the way, I've just ordered a copy of your C# in Depth.. Gosh I was trying to figure out where I heard your name from :)) I hope my code will compile after reading and learning from the book! :)

Comment: Yes after looking through it, you are right.. I have written this class in C# and referenced it in a vb.net project. So I might have messed things up a little while copying from both projects. Sorry for that, I'll edit my code now but you get the picture...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) on your string.

```
allowedChars = Regex.Escape(str.ToString());
```

ought to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `Regex.Escape`.